# Ubuntu 14.04 / HP3520 printer driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu version 14.04 from 12.04 but I cannot now print to my hp3520 printer anymore.

Any advice / suggestions?
Do I need to find / re-install a driver?
If so how and where from?

Answer (score 0):

Part way through downloading the latest HPLIP, my wife told me that her Ubuntu 12.04 installation was also not able to use the printer. Since that had been working fine, I ended up shutting off the printer and modem/router, restarting the modem/router, and then restarting the printer. Both 12.04 (with a its previously updated hplip) and 14.04 with its stock hplip were able to recognize the printer then. Appears to have been a network problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install `hplip-gui` if you do not have it:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

It contains a lot of commands starting with `hp-`, (try `hp-<TAB>` in a shell).

Start with [`hp-check`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/hp-check.1.html) 
, which looks for dependencies required by the `hp-*` tools, and explains problems, or fixes them automatically.
There is a similar tool `hp-doctor`; it's unclear to me what the difference is. (No man page - `hp-doctor -h` for help).

Then run `hp-plugin` (it may not be needed for the printer, but it does no harm).

Continue with [`hp-setup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/hp-setup.1.html) , and [`hp-toolbox`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/hp-toolbox.1.html) for setup and main options.